SSRS Multi Value Parameters with a MySQL Data Source (ODBC)
I am using SSRS 2022 (reports created in Report Builder v15) to connect to a MySQL database using an ODBC connection (MySQL ODBC driver 8.0) in my data source.  The data source connection tests successfully in both the SSRS web app and in Report Builder.
For the life of me, I cannot get multi-value parameters to work with the data source.  Note: because of the ODBC connection, you're supposed to use a question mark syntax when referring to the parameter.
In most cases, when I select more than one value in my parameter list and click "View Report", I get the following error: "Cannot add multi value query parameter '?' for dataset 'DataSet1' because it is not supported by the data extension. (rsErrorAddingMultiValueQueryParameter)
When I try #3 below, the report does not crash, but only seems to recognize the first value I've selected in the parameter list.
When I try #6 below, I get a syntax error.
I have tried:

referencing the parameter in my query like (what I thought was) normal: div.ID in (?)
in my dataset properties, setting the parameter name to ? and the value to [@parameter1]
in my dataset properties, setting the value to =Join(Parameters!parameter1.Value, ",")
ensuring that the parameter properties as viewed from the report has "Allow multiple values" checked
joining to a table as follows: ,(select @div_var := ?) as init_vars then saying and div.ID in (@div_var) in my where clause
building my query in the query designer (like an expression) and setting the expression to "...in ('" & Join(Parameters!div_var.Value, "', '") & "')
adding the parameter as a dataset filter

